# How to search for values from one file in another without using grep?

Tags: linux, awk, getline

I have two files. File 1 and file2, contents​ are as below. I want to find value in file2 against file 1.

Searching that I got below query but I am unable to understand.

Query:

```
cat file1 | awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{while(getline<"file2"){OFS=",";a[$2]=$1","$2","$3}} {print $0,a[$1]}' >> Final
```

File1

```
173
149
133
162
```

File2

```
140, dog
145, cat
149, rat
133, frog
160, lion
162, total
```

Please note: normal grep takes lots of time as size of file 2 is very big.

Comment: Just for the record awk makes absolute matching while grep does pattern matching. in grep key matches keys, in awk not, unless you use awk pattern matching (~/pattern/)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I think that should be s/absolute/string/ and s/pattern/regexp/. Never use the word "pattern" as it's highly ambiguous - always use "string" or "regexp", whichever you mean at the time. And to be clear you're talking about the users specific posted script, not about awk in general. Vaibhav - if you're considering using getline make sure you read and fully understand all of the caveats discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou OK, I posted an awk solution to that question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352304/133219.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, no need for a feeding `cat`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' f1 f12
149, rat
133, frog
162, total
```

Explained:

```
awk -F, '   # set delimiter to ,
NR==FNR{    # process the first file
    a[$1]   # hash the keys to a
    next    # off to the next record
}
$1 in a     # for the second file, if key ($1) is found in hash, output record
' f1 f2     # file order is important
```